# Cursor color and contrast conflict

Tags: themes, cursor

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and was changing the appearances in config. I turned on the contrast mode in acessibility to see how it was and turned it off afterwards, but my mouse cursor became black.

If I use `sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme` the cursor just stays the same, no matter which I choose, even after rebooting.

The content of `/usr/share/icons/default/index.theme` is:

```
[Icon Theme]
Inherits=DMZ-White
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the cursor set is defined in the contrast mode's data. Have you ever tried modifying the contrast mode data?

Comment: If you mean turning it off, yes. Otherwise, what do you mean by modifying its data?

Comment: There is some risks involved trying to edit the contrast mode data. Accept those risks, and go on and modify its data.